# VScrollBar Resizing

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscroll

I have got a C# WinForms application where a `splitterPanel` contains a `Form`;

```
Form myform = (Form)new CustomFrm();
myform.TopLevel = false;
myform.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
myform.Show();
splitter.Panel1.Controls.Add(myform);
```

`myform` is larger than `Panel1` and I'd like the panel autoscroll bars to show. Is this possible even if the Form is not a scrollable controll?

Answer (score 0):

> myform is larger than Panel1

Well that is only how you have designed it.

But then you set the `DockStyle` to `Fill` and now, when you do

```
splitter.Panel1.Controls.Add(myform);
```

the docking style will indeed make the `Form` **fill** the `Panel`; that is its `Size` is now equal to the panel's `Clientsize`.

Do not set it to `DockStyle.Fill`! Instead simply control the `Location = Point.Empty` and you should be set.

Comment: I ended up turning the forms into UserControls which solved the problem